# adding go modules to github repo

Tags: github

I've made a go repo in my github dir:

```
github
   go
     README.md
     .gitignore
```

and I want to create folders for each go project and make each folder a module and so on. However when I navigate inside each project directory, and:

```
 "git add .; git commit -m "first commit"; git remote add origin [repo] (in this case github.com/go); then push -u",
```

it just adds the go.mod file and nothing else which is an issue because then every change I make to a go.mod file even if its in a different directory will override the same one, since there is just one.

How do I make it so it adds the folder so I can have multiple modules in the same go repo?